# Java Swing ignores attributes set to the specific components

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, edt

I'm working on an IntelliJ plugin using Gradle and the Java Swing library. I've realized that some of the attributes I'm setting are getting ignored like **the Background** or the **color of the Border**. For example:

```
textField.setBackgroundColor(Colors.customColor);
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Colors.anotherColor));
```

I've tried moving those declarations to the Event Dispatch Thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I've also tried calling the `repaint()` method afterwards, but it also doesn't help.

The other aspect of the problem is the light or dark mode of the IDE. At switching the mode, the colors get overridden. And since they are referenced to the components, I assumed it is enough to only call the `repaint()` method afterwards. Unfortunately, it is not. It seems that there are some concurrency issues, but I cannot find anything on the internet about it.

Comment: Some L&F may ignore these properties when they provide image-based background painting. In this case your can only provide your own UI for the component based on BasicTextFieldUI, that tries to imitate the L&F of Idea.

Comment: You should make a complete compilable example with what you want and what you're getting. For example, a JTextField has multiple places you might consider the "background". One of the "backgounds" will not be displayed unless the component is opaque.

Comment: There are definitely concurrency issues, if you’re doing any of this work in a thread other than the event dispatch thread.  All Swing methods have undefined behavior if called in any other thread—meaning, sometimes they’ll work and sometimes they won’t.